Rancher Desktop 'craches' during first start
I want to write a program and run it via containerization. And I want to ask you, if you can assist me with the problems I have.
I have chosen Rancher Desktop as the environment.
However, I have a few problems with it:

If I get it to "run", my docker-compose up is not recognized (error during connect: in the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run with elevated privileges to connect). Even if I start Rancher Desktop with administrator rights, I get this error.

Every time I reinstall Rancher Desktop (whether via Power Shell (also as administrator) or by double-clicking), the program gets stuck during the start configuration (no response from the program) and I have to restart my computer.


During this time, my entire system seems to freeze, I can hardly do anything (and I don't seem to have any internet at all).
I have Windows 10 (latest version) on the host system. WSL and WSL 2 are installed (Ubuntu). Virtualization is enabled in the BIOS (Gigabyte B550 Gaming X V2, current BIOS). I use docker-compose.yaml to collect information about other Dockerfiles:

I don't know if it helps at this point, but:

I don't need Kubernetes
I would like to use docker-compose up to start my server (I use IntelliJ, Java)

Thanks in advance.
P.S.: I just activated Hyper-V via control panel.
P.S.S.: I hope the problem is not that it is docker-compose.yml instead of [...].yaml...

I solved my problem.
I uninstalled all instances of WSL (wsl, ubuntu) and Rancher Desktop.
Then I followed the instructions for installing Docker Desktop exactly. Done.
